# External access to internet from Kubernetes Pods

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I'm having troubles with network access from pods. I had installed new Kubernetes cluster with flannel-network plugin,
Checking the health of server - good.

I tried to check network via busybox: `kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox -n microservices --image=busybox sh`, then `ping 8.8.8.8` results in drop.

But `ping 8.8.8.8` succeeded when executed from `kubectl exec -it kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xxxx -n kube-system` (checking network inside flannel pod).

What can it be? 
I think it can be something with flannel or docker network configuration. But i did not find information about it.

I tried to change iptables configs, reinit cluster, create and changing docker network interfaces.

I have no more ideas, what can I do?

P.S. There is the same server installed before me and their settings and installation procedure are identical. And their connection is good.

Comment: Do you have ipv4 forwarding enabled? See: https://success.docker.com/article/ipv4-forwarding

Comment: Yes, without ip-forwarding kubectl init does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution ...

Check your network interfaces (`ifconfig -a cni0`).
Good config is:

> cni0: flags=4163  mtu 1450
>           inet 10.244.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0...

That subnet (10.244.0.0) configured in [flannel-deploy.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml)

But, by default, a new server may have:

> cni0: flags=4163  mtu 1450
>           inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0...

Change it to:

`ifconfig eth0 10.244.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 0.0.0.0`